# Ubuntu problem at the beginning

Tags: grub2, keyboard

I have a problem at the beginning on ubuntu, after I start my computer, there comes a purple screen what says:

"gnu grub version 1.99-21ubuntu3

*list of ubuntu versions*

Use the arrows to move and enter to boot the selected OS.
Press E to edit the commands before booting or "C" for a command-line"

OK, most of you would say, "open the command line" but its not so easy, no matter hell how I try to press my keyboard buttons, it wont do anything, I tried all buttons on my keyboard but it wont do anything... And yes my keyboard works and I've tried different keyboards, and there is no way to skip that screen, so can someone who is a good with these things, tell me what to do next? :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. You cannot see the topbar and launcher when you log in? DO you, by any chance, have an Nvidia graphics card? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Add this data to the question please.

Comment: It may not be a freeze, it may not be recognising the keyboard.  If you are using a wireless keyboard, try plugging in a USB keyboard in and see if it works with that.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard USB port isn't turned on, most of the times it happens because at the startup of the system the only USB ports that works properly are the ones directly connected to the motherboard, so try changing the USB port that your keyboard is attached to.

If the problem persits even trying all the possible USB ports you will need to skip Grub (purple screen where you select the OS), if you have a dual-boot system (Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine) you will have some problems because you won't be able to switch between then, but if you have just Ubuntu installed in your pc just do these steps to reinstall Ubuntu and get rid of the problem:

1. Create a Live CD/USB
2. Startup the Live CD/USB and select to "try Ubuntu without installing it"
3. Wait the desktop to load and select to install Ubuntu
4. Doing a fresh install you should start Ubuntu without passing through Grub

So now your problem should be solved.